# Create database ER diagram for existing DB - javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, entity-relationship, dbvisualizer

I want to create an ER diagram for a database schema using D3js (Or any other js lib if you have some suggestions). I want to create it because I didn't find the service that fits my needs. I want the diagram to update every time someone changes the DB schema (Adds a table, update, etc). I want an automatic layout for importing a DB schema (With dbml, XML, or other options), and I want the user to be able to move nodes.

I couldn't find any examples or tutorials. does someone have any suggestions or examples (Or a service that fits those needs)?